# INSERT INTO: mysql_real_escape_string alternative

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
 $q = "INSERT INTO articles VALUES( mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["article"]) )
 $req = $bdd->prepare($q); 
 $req ->execute();
```

I've been working on another server where mysql_real_escape_string() is still not obsolete, and now I'm moving the site to another mysql server which apparently doesn't accept this function anymore. And, it's pretty clear I need to use some PDOs

SO what's the PDO equivalent for mysql_real_escape_string()? I'm trying something like this

```
 $idc = new PDO(...);
 $q = "INSERT INTO articles VALUES( $idc->quote(($_GET["article"])));
 $req = $bdd->prepare($q); 
 $req ->execute();
```

I do use prepared statements, but I suspect my PDO::quote is wrong somewhere.

But it doesn't render the same result... 
Thank you.

Comment: If you're using PDO, you should be using prepared statements. BTW, your original statement wouldn't have worked, since functions aren't evaluated inside strings -- you need to use concatenation.

Comment: What result do you get from `quote`?  Also are you putting `mysql_real_escape_string` or `quote` directly into the query?  Because that won't work...

Comment: if you suspect something - why not to try a manual page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO::quote` is the equivalent of `mysql_real_escape_string`. If there's some reason you can't use a prepared statement, you can use it like this:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO articles VALUES (" . $idc->quote($_GET["article"]) . ")";
```

A significant difference is that it includes the surrounding quotes around the string, while `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't (so you would have to put quotes in your `INSERT` string).

Answer (score 0):

Use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)(preferred) or [`PDO::quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)